# UISplitViewController automatically 'segues' to detail viewController

Tags: swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm setting up a UISplitViewController programatically. This code appears to automatically segue to the detailViewController which is unwanted behaviour. Instead I would like it to present the masterViewController and let the user chose the detailViewController with `didSelectRowAt IndexPath`. Any help appreciated.

```
let splitViewController = UISplitViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
let masterNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MasterViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil))
let detailNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: DetailViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil))
splitViewController.viewControllers = [masterNavigationController, detailNavigationController]
present(splitViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement the `UISplitViewControllerDelegate` method `splitViewController(_:showDetail:sender:)` (documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisplitviewcontrollerdelegate/1623204-splitviewcontroller)) to override the behaviour of your split vc.

In your specific case it should return true all the time except the time when the split vc is presented initially. In this case, you could set up a flag variable, e.g.

```
var isInitialState: Bool = true
```

then set it to false once the split vc has been presented completely – here I'm not sure when would be the best time, but I would guess

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
[...]
  isInitialState = false
[...]
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This didn't work for me, but it did lead me to a solution which was to use `splitViewController(_ splitViewController: collapseSecondary secondaryViewController:onto primaryViewController:)`